# -moz-transform-origin has no effect on SVG transition

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have an svg which contains one path and one polygon. Each of these have a class and I am using CSS3 transitions to animate them.

This is working perfectly in Chrome and Safari. In IE and Opera the transitions don't happen at all, it just changes colour which is fine - it's not ideal but at least it doesn't look *bad*.

However, on Firefox the shapes animate from the top-left corner and are cropped by the edge of the SVG. This is the same behaviour as you would get on Chrome if you do not include -webkit-transform-origin but the problem remains after adding -moz-transform-origin.

Examples: [Copepen](http://codepen.io/mrchimp/pen/sLjkp), [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKx4X/)

My HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <svg version="1.0" width="62" height="62" viewBox="0 0 62 62" xml:space="preserve" class="svg">
    <defs id="defs3003"></defs>
    <path d="M 31,6 C 17.192,6 6,17.192 6,31 6,44.808 17.192,56 31,56 44.808,56 56,44.808 56,31 56,17.192 44.808,6 31,6 m 0,45.313 C 19.781,51.313 10.687,42.219 10.687,31 10.687,19.781 19.781,10.688 31,10.688 c 11.219,0 20.313,9.093 20.313,20.312 0,11.219 -9.094,20.313 -20.313,20.313" id="path2997" style="fill:#ffffff" class="ring"></path>
    <polygon points="22.75,41.938 22.75,20.063 41.5,31 " transform="translate(0.86055955,-5e-4)" id="polygon2999" style="fill:#ffffff" class="inner"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
.overlay .svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
}
.overlay .svg .inner {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
       -o-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.2s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.2s;
          transition: all linear 0.2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  fill: #fff !important;
}
.overlay:hover .svg .inner {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
       -o-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.1s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.1s;
          transition: all linear 0.1s;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  fill: #FA0 !important;
}

.overlay .svg .ring {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
       -o-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.25s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.25s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.25s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.25s;
          transition: all linear 0.25s;
  fill: #fff !important;
}

.overlay:hover .svg .ring {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
       -o-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.15s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.15s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.15s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.15s;
          transition: all linear 0.15s;
  fill: #FA0 !important;
}
```

Comment: For those who hate codepen like I do - http://jsfiddle.net/bKx4X/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble with transitions using SVG. Have you tried using only HTML?

I've changed our code to use only HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/labmorales/kkVnY/1/

HTML

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="svg">
        <div class="ring">
            <div class="inner"></div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
.overlay .svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;  
}
.overlay .svg .inner {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -moz-transform-origin: 32px 32px;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
       -o-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.2s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.2s;
          transition: all linear 0.2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;  
    border-left: 15px solid #fff;
    margin: 13px 24px;
    /*background: #fff !important;*/
}
.overlay:hover .svg .inner {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
       -o-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.1s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.1s;
          transition: all linear 0.1s;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  border-left: 15px solid #FA0; 
  /*background: #FA0 !important;*/
}

.overlay .svg .ring {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;  
  height: 50px; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -moz-transform-origin: 32px 32px;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
       -o-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.25s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.25s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.25s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.25s;
          transition: all linear 0.25s;
  /*fill: #fff !important;*/
}

.overlay:hover .svg .ring {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
       -o-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.15s;
     -moz-transition: all linear 0.15s;
      -ms-transition: all linear 0.15s;
       -o-transition: all linear 0.15s;
          transition: all linear 0.15s;
  /*fill: #FA0 !important;*/
  border-color: #FA0 !important;   
}
```

Worked here on Firefox, Chrome, IE9(without transitions) on Windows7. I hope it helps!

Comment: It seems Firefox just doesn't handle transitions on individual parts of an SVG very well. I have a few different icons - not just the play button - so doing it in HTML alone wasn't really possible. I ended up making two separate SVGs which works great. I'll accept your answer anyway - it's as good as any! Thanks!